# How to get custom object in VS Code

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, vs-code

I would like to setup a dev environment using Visual Studio Code. I'm able to do that with the help of Salesforce Extension Pack.
I want to fetch all custom object in VS Code. How Can I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To achieve this goal in the VS Code you can use two ways.
Please find below

1. Package.xml
   => Add Object member type in package.XML
2. Org browser Extension
   => You can Retrieve selected components like custom objects.
   [image: Org Browser Extension]

Answer (score 5):

you can run this command: `sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomObject`

you can also added the node CustomObject to your package.xml file

Comment: Where Should I run this command in Command Palette (Ctrl + Shift +P)?

Comment: @RaviShah `Ctrl+Shift+~` to open the Terminal, then run it from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the command: **sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomObject** in the VS code terminal
Alternatively, I found a VS Code extension using which you you can fetch metadata from the org - '**Salesforce Package.xml Generator Extension for VS Code**'. Try installing and using it. Using it , you can update package.xml and use it to fetch the metadata